# How do I get a Paragraph Element with Html Unit and Xpath

Tags: java, html, xpath, htmlunit

Hi I´m fairly new to HtmlUnit, I got a project where I want to fetch some information from a side and till now everything went smooth finding elements via name or id. But I was unable to get the following Paragraph Element.

```
<iframe id="content_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" title=".." style="width: 100%; height: 307px; display: block;">
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody content post-type-coupon wp-editor" contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('content').onLoad.dispatch();" dir="ltr">
<p>------ Text from the Element i want to get ------- </p>
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

I tried already:

```
side.getByXPath("//html/body/p");// zero elements
side.getByXpath("//p");// 27 element but wrong.
side.getByXpath("//body");// 1 element but wrong.
side.getByXpath("//html");// 1 element but wrong.
side.getByXpath("//html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[4]/form/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/span/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/iframe"); // Zero elements found
```

I checked all elements the Code found with this:

```
List<?> list =gPage.getByXPath("//p");
    for(Object x:list){
        HtmlElement y=(HtmlElement) x;
        if(y.asXml().contains("Keyword")||y.asText().contains("Keyword")){
        System.out.println(y.asText());
        }
```

So in conclusion I couldn´t find the Paragraph Element by his Text. Could you help me find the Paragraph element, so that I´m able to read and write from/to it?

```
        //Initialize WebClient
        final WebClient webClient= new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
        webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

        //Perform a login.
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("");        
        final HtmlForm form = page.getForms().get(1);
        final HtmlTextInput username = form.getInputByName("log");
        final HtmlPasswordInput pw = form.getInputByName("pwd");
        username.setValueAttribute("");
        pw.setValueAttribute("");
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        HtmlPage page2 =  (HtmlPage) form.getButtonByName("login").click();

        //Get gutscheinPage
        HtmlPage gutscheinPage= webClient.getPage("");

        //Change Content of Textfield
        HtmlPage pageFrame = (HtmlPage) gutscheinPage.getFrames().get(0).getEnclosedPage();
        HtmlElement body =pageFrame.getBody();
        HtmlParagraph p =(HtmlParagraph) body.getByXPath("//p").get(0);
        p.setTextContent(text);
```

Done: Change the webClient default Browser and wait for Jscript,use getFrames, find the body and use the now easy XPath to provide me with my Paragraph Element.

I really hope someone will find this helpfull for their own work.

Thanks for every answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, it's in an `iframe`. I guess you need switch into the frame first.

[Here](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/frame-howto.html) is the documentation which you should have a try.

```
// untested Java code, please debug and read documentation yourself

final List<FrameWindow> window = page.getFrames();
final HtmlPage pageTwo = (HtmlPage) window.get(0).getEnclosedPage();

// then find TinyMCE's body, which should be treated as a separated HTML page
```

Comment: This works now, added some extra Code on the webClient. `final WebClient webClient= new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);` and `webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);`